# how can get the style of a paragraph with openxml wordprecessingml in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I'm new to openxml,and I know the wordprocessingml style as described here:

[Style Part of a WordprocessingML Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669110.aspx)

How to get the style of a paragraph with openxml in c#?

For example I want the paragraphs with this style: it is "blue" with the size "14" and blue color.

Comment: need clarification: do you need the applied style name of the paragraph or the formatting of the paragraph like the font, size color the paragraph is using?